# Reporter not updating in netlogo behaviorspace

Tags: netlogo

I using a reporter in the "Measure runs using reporters:" for every step to ouput a set of global variables in netlogo behaviorspace but after the variables are updated for the first step, further updates of the values for each variable are no longer output to the spreadsheet/ table that is the end product of a netlogo behaviourspace batch simulation. What would cause of this issue? Ideally, I would like for the resulting spreadsheet to show changes to the values of the global variables/ parameters that occur at each step (updating by ticks). Has anyone encountered this issue before? Any ideas on how to resolve such issues would be extremely appreciated. My code is a little too lofty to post on here, otherwise I would!

Comment: can you please post a screenshot of your behaviorspace setup?

Comment: @JenB It runs now. I needed to avoid setting globals within the code since behaviorspace gives options for such settings prior to batch simulation runs.